# How do you invert a non-invertable matrix with an epsilon?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, approximation, singularity

The inverse of a Y-paramter matrix (admittance, used in RF for wave behavior) represents a Z-parameter matrix (impedance, ie, $Z=Y^{-1}$).  Unfortunately the [math library we are using](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::LinearAlgebra) thinks the provided Y-matrix determinant is nearly 0, and therefore non-invertible.  Really it is just *close* to zero, but really *is* invertible.

I would like to "tweak" the Y matrix before and after the inversion to get the library above its threshold of floating-point "zero" (probably 1e-6).

[This discussion](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_find_an_inverse_of_a_singular_matrix_but_not_with_the_Moore-Penrose_method) talks about inverting a non-invertible matrix by adding an epsilon, but it doesn't extrapolate on the method. I'm guessing its something like this when $\epsilon$ is small:

$ (A + \epsilon I)^{-1} \approx A^{-1}$

Its okay if the resulting matrix is nearly singular.

Questions:

- Can you remove $\epsilon$ after the inversion?
- If so, how?

More background:

Often Y/Z matrices are 2x2, but could be bigger. Y and Z matrices are obtained from S-parameter matrices, typically from real-life network analyzer measurements, so there is always noise in the matrix and adding a small amount of additional error isn't a big deal if we can keep it small or remove it after the conversion.

Comment: Looks like the package has eigenvalue and eigenvector calculation. You could have it calculate those, then create the inverse. This could go awry if your matrix is also nearly defective, but seems pretty unlikely you'll get one that's both nearly singular and nearly defective.

Comment: I have no idea what you intend to achieve, but if you know in advance that $A$ is non-invertible, it does not make sense to tweak the parameters to make it invertible. On the other hand, every (invertible or non-invertible) real or complex matrix $A$ has a [Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), which can be obtained as the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}(A^\ast A+\epsilon I)^{-1}A^\ast$.

Comment: To clarify, $A$ has Schur decomposition $A=QUQ^{-1}$, so the eigenvalues of $A$ can be uniformly shifted by $\varepsilon$ by computing $A+\varepsilon I=Q(U+\varepsilon I)Q^{-1}$. When A is positive semidefinite, this is sometimes referred to as [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization), and is an effective method of lowering the condition number of $A$.

Comment: This is one of the scourges of numerical analysis and it is very difficult to get away from.  Suppose instead that you want to invert a $1\times1$ matrix, that is a number, and it is close to zero, and carries a bit of noise.  Say the number is $10^{-7}$ and the noise is of the order of $10^{-6}$.  Depending on the noise the result may be pretty much any real number bigger than $10^6$.  In other words it is likely to be meaningless.